# where is the memory leak in this PHP code snippet?

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I have a PHP code snippet that reads in apache access logs for processing. I've stripped down the code to these few lines and I still find the leak. The PHP process keeps taking up more and more memory, even though the echo memory_get_usage() keeps reporting 11Mb each time.

Running with PHP 5.3.6 on an Ubuntu 12 machine. Problem goes away with PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu.

```
$logDir = opendir(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tempLog');
while (($file = readdir($logDir)) !== false) {
    echo($file . PHP_EOL);

    $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tempLog' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
    $fhandle = fopen($filePath, 'r');
    fseek($fhandle, 0);

    while(!feof($fhandle)) {
        $line = fgets($fhandle);
    }

    fclose($fhandle);
    echo('Finished reading!' . PHP_EOL);
    echo('Memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
    system('cat /proc/' . getmypid() . '/status | grep VmSize');
}
```

EDIT: added sample output from this script: 
EDIT2: added VM size

```
access.log.2
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:       54972 kB

access.log.19
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:       55896 kB

access.log.23
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:       81372 kB

access.log.41
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:       93120 kB

access.log.31
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:      107508 kB

access.log.28
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:      112128 kB

access.log.5
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303616
VmSize:      112920 kB

..
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303592
VmSize:      112920 kB

.
Finished reading!
Memory usage: 11303592
VmSize:      112920 kB
```

Any ideas where the memory leak might be? and how I might avoid it?

Comment: As a WAG, i'd guess that the `while` loop is to blame. Probably something to do with `fgets`.

Comment: as a wife and girlfriend? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAGs

Comment: Apache access logs can get very large, how big are the ones you are trying to parse?

Comment: @mike this should not matter with fgets. Have you tried another php version?

Comment: First of all you should check whether `$file` variable isn't `.` or `..`. In case it is, you should `continue` the loop. I've just testet your code, and it seems fine, no memory leaks detected.

Comment: @75inchpianist, ["WAG, an acronym for 'wild ass guess', an estimate based on experience or similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wag_(disambiguation))

Comment: @MikePurcell they are not that large, as they get rotated daily. Largest one is about 24Mb

Comment: @Crozin Yes, another colleague also noticed he has no memory leak on his system. Seems to be an issue with my PHP version or OS?

Comment: It seems that it could be PHP/OS dependent. Could you please post memory usage? The differences between files should be dependent on the size of the file last line.

Comment: @Crozin: you want the output from running this? Or the system memory usage?

Comment: You could post any data you consider useful in any way.

Comment: You mention your collegue had no issue, as did Crozin, which PHP versions did they test against? If you deem that it isn't a PHP version issue, you may want to try using the SplFile api: http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.files.php

Comment: Have you tried enabling garbage collection?

Comment: colleague on OSX with PHP 5.3.13

Comment: Obvious response to the problem is to get off of 5.3.6, are you able to do so? FTR, 5.3 end of life is March 2013, so you might want to consider switching to 5.4.

Comment: @MikePurcell its for software that will be released, so we have to it should run under reasonable versions of PHP

Comment: I added proof of the leak

Comment: problem goes away with PHP 5.2

Comment: Try using the splfile API, see if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't do garbage collection by default (it seems from a skim of the manual). There's a couple of things you could do.

1) Enable GC with `gc_enable()`. You can force a GC pass using `gc_collect_cycles()`.

2) Explicitly destroy `$line` using `unset($line)`.

Comment: I've just realised this might not solve your problem. Another thing to try is to call `memory_get_usage` with the `TRUE` parameter to obtain the usage from the OS rather than PHP's internal counter. There could have been a bug in their allocator.

Comment: good suggestions, but neither helped. Passing in TRUE did not make a difference either...rather, it reports a slightly different amount of memory, but stil the same each iteration

Comment: Did you not get a different measure? How are you obtaining the the memory size from the OS?